# How to change code to make http://uri dynamic or parametrized?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration flow for post message:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpPost() {
   return IntegrationFlows
        .from("requestChannel")
        .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://uri")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
        .extractPayload(true))
        .get();
}
```

How to change code to make **http://uri** dynamic or parametrized?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Create an {@link HttpMessageHandlerSpec} builder for request-reply gateway
 * based on provided {@code Function} to evaluate target {@code uri} against request message.
 * @param uriFunction the {@code Function} to evaluate {@code uri} at runtime.
 * @param <P> the expected payload type.
 * @return the HttpMessageHandlerSpec instance
 */
public static <P> HttpMessageHandlerSpec outboundGateway(Function<Message<P>, ?> uriFunction) {
    return outboundGateway(new FunctionExpression<>(uriFunction));
}
```

so

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway(message -> message.getHeaders().get("someHeaderWithURI"))
```

Alternativelt, you can use a SpEL expression.